# C++ Adding sum of multiple function calls within a loop

Tags: c++, function

I've been working on an assignment that calculates the total profit/loss for multiple stock sales via a looping function with information inputted by user for each stock sale. I did a thorough amount of googling to no avail. I was able to get the function working within the loop but I have not been able to figure out how to add the profit/loss from multiple sales - instead only displaying profit/loss for each individual function call. My function's algorithm checks out if you manually add the totals for each sale, just unclear on how to find the sum of multiple function calls.

Here is the sample data I'm suppose to enter that should display the total profit of $3324.00:

```
sale   numberOfShares   salePrice   salesCommission   purchasePrice   purchaseCommission
1      25               15          7.50              5               2.50
2      100              2.50        12                1.75            8
3      1000             5.10        51                2               20
```

And my code thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
double stockProfitFunction(double NS, double PP, double PC, double SP, double SC);


// Main Function
int main()
{
    // Format output
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    // Initialize variables
    double profit,
        numberOfShares,
        salePrice,
        saleCommission,
        purchasePrice,
        purchaseComission;
    int numberOfSales;

    // Get # of sales from user
    cout << "Multiple Stock Profit Calculator\n--------------------------------\n\n";
    cout << "How many sales do you wish to enter?: ";
    cin >> numberOfSales;
    cout << endl;

    // Perform function in loop for number of sales
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfSales; i++)
    {
        system("cls");  // Clears screen

        cout << "Multiple Stock Profit Calculator\n";
        cout << "(Currently entering stock sale #" << i << ")\n----------------------------------\n";

        // Get information from user
        cout << "Enter number of shares: ";
        cin >> numberOfShares;

        cout << "Enter sale price: ";
        cin >> salePrice;

        cout << "Enter sales commission: ";
        cin >> saleCommission;

        cout << "Enter purchase price: ";
        cin >> purchasePrice;

        cout << "Enter purchase commission: ";
        cin >> purchaseComission;

        //Calcualtes profit with function
        profit = stockProfitFunction(numberOfShares, purchasePrice, purchaseComission, salePrice, saleCommission);


        // Display "profit" or "loss" depending on positive or negative value returned by function
        if (profit >= 0)
        {
            cout << "\n-----------------------\n";
            cout << "You earned a profit of: $" << profit << endl;
            cout << "(Press enter to input next sale)";
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n-----------------------\n";
            cout << "You had a loss of: $" << profit << endl;
            cout << "(Press enter to input next sale)";
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


// Stock Profit Function, returns profit
double stockProfitFunction(double NS, double PP, double PC, double SP, double SC)
{
    return ((NS * SP) - SC) - ((NS * PP) + PC);
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Initialize a variable to zero.
2. Each time you calculate a profit, add it to that variable.
3. Where desired, output the value of that variable.

By the way:

```
system("cls");  // Clears screen
```

That's a very bad habit to get into. Maybe on your machine, `cls` clears the screen, but you have no way to know what the `cls` command might do on someone else's machine. (On mine, there is no command called `cls`, the clear screen command is `clear`.) Unless you absolutely have no choice, you should strongly avoid using `system` in your C++ code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, David. Out of curiosity, why do I need to initialize the variable to zero? I understand it won't compile without doing so, just not sure exactly why. Also, my textbook suggested using system("cls"); for windows pcs and system("clear"); for unix systems, which in itself seems to highlight exactly what you mentioned. Is there a safer way to achieve a similar result?

Comment: If you don't initialize it to zero, the value is indeterminate and so you won't know what will happen after the first time you add to it. It might work, or it might not. As for safely clearing the screen, it's inherently complicated. How do you know the user is even using a screen as opposed to, say, a printer? And there is no standard that is guaranteed to work for every screen. Perhaps the input is coming from some other program. It's non-trivial and I would suggest just not doing it unless you have no choice. Learn C++ first and learn fancy terminal tricks later.